# Are these bipartite graphs Hamiltonian graphs? And do they have a name?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, hamiltonian-path

Assume that $n = 2k + 1$, and 
$$A = \{ \alpha \in \{\,0,1 \,\}^{n} \mid w(\alpha) = k + 1 \}$$
$$B = \{ \alpha  \in \{\,0,1 \,\}^{n} \mid w(\alpha) = k \}$$
where $w(\cdot)$ is the Hamming weight.

Let $V = A \cup B$ and 
$$E = \{ (\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}) \in V \times V \mid d(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}) = 1 \}$$

where $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the Hamming distance. It is obvious that $G = (V,E)$ is a bipartite graph.

Q1: Is $G$ a Hamiltonian graph?

Q2: I believe that there is a name of this "combinatorial problem" or "graph" or "code", do you know that?

As for $n = 5$, I give a Hamiltonian cycle here.
$$(01110,01100,01101,00101, \\
00111,00110,10110,10010,\\
10011,00011,01011,01001, \\
11001,10001,10101,10100,\\
11100,11000,11010,01010)$$

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you Misha, I momentarily overlooked the $n=2k+1$ comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *bipartite Kneser graph* $H(n,k)$ is the graph with vertex set consisting of:

- $A$, the set of all $k$-element subsets of $\{1,2, \dots,n\}$, and
- $B$, the set of all $(n-k)$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

A vertex $S \in A$ and a vertex $T \in B$ are adjacent if and only if $S \subseteq T$.

Your graph is a special case of this graph: it is the graph $H(2k+1,k)$. (In my notation, $A$ and $B$ are swapped from yours: $A$ corresponds to the weight-$k$ strings of length $n$ and $B$ corresponds to the weight-$(k+1)$ strings.) It also has a special name, the *middle layer graph*.

---

The graph $H(n,k)$ is Hamiltonian for any $k \ge 1$ and $n \ge 2k+1$, so the middle layer graph is also Hamiltonian, but this is a relatively recent - and not easy - result. It was proven:

- For the middle layer graph in 2014 by Torsten Mütze (*Proof of the middle levels conjecture*, Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society, 2016, [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4442)).
- In general in 2015 by Torsten Mütze and Pascal Su (*Bipartite Kneser graphs are Hamiltonian*, Combinatorica, 2017, [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.09175)).